# How to do an Automated build in TFS 2010 by a label

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have my automated builds working but I want to be able to go back to a specifc labeled version and build from that source.  The build definition under "Process" has the item "Get Version" but this is for a specific changeset which seems fairly useless.  Does anyone have any idea how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 19):

The Get Version accepts what TFS calls an versionspec which can be either a changeset or a label.  To specify a label just prefix it with an L.

LMyLabel

Comment: +1 its also worth mentioning that team build creates a label for the souce included in each build

Comment: This could be testes. It works. So you should mark it as answer

Answer (score 3):

@Dylan Smith: Is right. You can specify in the advanced Get Version parameter the label by: LmyLabel or CmyChangeset in order to queue a specific version. There are other options like date, "W" (Version last fetched to your workspace), or "T" (latest version) as well.

For more information:  [Building a Specific Version with Team Build 2008](http://readcommit.blogspot.com.es/2008/06/building-specific-version-with-team.html)

Answer (score 0):

During your build process, label the code (In my case I use the build number as part of the label).

Then when you want to build a specific labeled version, pass the label to the build script, get the code from the library by label, build the code, and deploy.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx for how to get a labeled version.